# Array initialization spelling

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I wrote a function that converts any letter from an array into lowercase, but I want the functionality to be in the main function without using the  function I wrote.
Somehow I cant do it or don't recognize my mistake:

this is my function:

```
    void lower(char *a) {

        for (int n = 0; n < strlen(a); n++) {
            a[n] = tolower(a[n]);
         }
     }
```

and my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {


if (strcmp(*(argv + 0), "./lower") == 0)  
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)     
        {
            
            for (int n = 0; n < strlen(argv[i]); n++) // <- this is my problem
            {
                **(argv+n) = tolower(**(argv+n));
            }
        }

     
        return 2;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I want to do it in the if statement without the function, but don't know where the problem is.
It works when I use my function.

Comment: Using a function is a better idea than including the code verbatim in `main()`.  Use functions — lots of functions.  Do not make large, monolithic functions, especially not in `main()`.

Comment: `(argv + 0)` doesn't look like a very interesting expression. Furthermore, the utility of this  conditional is questionable.

Comment: i heard that *(a+0) is the same as a[0] . isnt that right ?

Comment: So write `argv[0]` and not `*(argv + 0)` — it's simpler, easier to understand, more reliable, common sense, and what experienced C programmers expect to see.  The other notation is prevalent on SO, but mainly from novice users.

Comment: It's inefficient to call strlen on every loop. Better is to stop on  0 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it easier to read and instead of double-pointer use single pointer. It will make the pointer arithmetic more simple (`**(argv+n)` is not what you want).

```
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            char *temp = argv[i];
            while(*temp)
            {
                *temp = tolower((unsigned char)*temp);
                temp++;
            }
        }
```